# Django Admin ForeignKey issue,

Tags: python, django, admin

The following are my models in Django.

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_books = models.IntegerField(default =0)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors, on_delete = models.CASCADE)`
```

I want to use Admin platform to achieve: when I add a new Book, the total_books in related author add 1. Is there any way to solve it?

I would appropriate it if someone help me.

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a method to do this. Your approach results in more writing to the database than needed. You could even go with a property:

```py
class Authors(models.Model):
    ...
    @property
    def book_count(self):
        return self.book_set.count()
```

The syntax with `<object>_set` is the default implementation of reverse lookups in django. Search for '_set' [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/) to find more examples.

Then, when you "grab" an author you can easily get the book_count like this:

```py
a = Authors.objects.first()
print(a.book_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [Tarquinius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76825618/13153088) answer:

if you want to display book_count property in your admin panel, you should add list_display and readonly_fields to your ModelAdmin:

```
class AuthorsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('your_fields', 'book_count', )
   readonly_fields = ('your_fields', 'book_count', ) # object detail page

admin.site.register(Authors, AuthorsAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include method inside Authors for updating count.

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_book_count(self,instance):
        book_count = Book.objects.filter(author__pk=self.pk).count()
        instance.total_books=book_count
        instance.save()
```

And call this method using [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/signals/) after book is created.
Pass instance of Author to it.